# What is the correct configuration to let the HTTPS traffic goes to containers with Docker and Traefik?

Tags: docker, iis, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I got a docker swarm configure with Traefik has the reverse-proxy. I got a service where my SSL traffic should be routed.

I got my certificate SSL configure with traefik and traefik is able to resolve them correctly, and served them the client.

But, i would like to let the SSL traffic go to my containers (they also have the SSL certificate).

I try different ways but each witout any success.

Here is the label i use with my service

No success with this one

```
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z0-9]+}.mydomain.com`)
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.entrypoints=https       
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.service=localhost-https
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.priority=2
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.tls=true     
   - traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true       
   - traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.server.port=443
   - traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https
```

No success with this one to

```
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z0-9]+}.mydomain.com`)
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.entrypoints=https       
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.service=localhost-https
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.priority=2
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.tls=true     
   - traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true       
   #- traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.server.port=443
   - traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https
```

The only one with who i got success .. but do not reach our goal is this configuration

```
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z0-9]+}.mydomain.com`)
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.entrypoints=https       
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.service=localhost-https
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.priority=2
   - traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.tls=true     
   - traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true       
   - traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.server.port=80
   #- traefik.http.services.localhost-https.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https
```

How could i let the traffic continue to my container in SSL ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: @samwu thank for your comment. I completely reedit the question. In fact IIS did have any incidence in my case. I think the problem is about routing the traffic correctly with Traefik.

Comment: I think you need to specify  `- traefik.http.routers.localhost-https.service=localhost-https@file`, and then define in the file provider a service, that can specify the target service using a full url including scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  a "Transport" to let traefik know that the SSL should be pass-though to the pod

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`#####`)
    services:
    - name: NAME
      namespace: NAMESPACE
      port: 8080
      scheme: https
      serversTransport: transport
  tls:
    domains:
    - main: '###'
    
---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: ServersTransport
spec:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
```

I pasted my config for Kubernetes resources, you should try to traduce this to the DockerSwarm config. I don't know how to do that but it should be quite straightforward